# I am trying to update an item in a sharepoint list but its returning Bad Request .NET core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, sharepoint, asp.net-core-3.1

```
class Program
{
    
    public static async Task<bool> Post(string siteUrl, string requestUri, HttpContent content)
    {
        var credential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(
            "User",
            "Pass",
            "Domain");

        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = credential, UseProxy = false })
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                 var mediaType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
                 mediaType.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("odata", "nometadata"));
                 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(mediaType);
                 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-RequestDigest", await GetRequestDigest());
                 string url = string.Format(requestUri, siteUrl);
                 HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
                 response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                 return true;
            }
        }
    }

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string domain = "xxxx";
        string SiteUrl = "https://SITE/";
        string issuesListById = "{0}_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('issues')/items?$filter=ID eq 1";
        string taskListUrlById = "{0}_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('tasks')/items?$filter=ID eq 932";

        var credentials = new NetworkCredential("User", "Pass", domain);
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials };
        using (var http = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            var stringContent = new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = await http.GetAsync(string.Format(taskListUrlById, SiteUrl)).ConfigureAwait(false);
            string jsonData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tasks>(jsonData);
            var itemToEdit = obj.Value.First();
            itemToEdit.Status = "Close";
            var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var update = await Post(SiteUrl, taskListUrlById, content);
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to update the status of a task in a SharePoint list to "Close", I am using the post method to send the content, I am receiving "bad request" in the post method... I am using REST to communicate with SharePoint on Premise any idea on what causing this problem? (the GetRequestDigest function is working well). if someone can help... Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You send `Get` and `Post` with same `taskListUrlById`, and not use `issuesListById`, it's ok?

Comment: @Genusatplay yes I'm working on updating a task list item

Answer (score 1):

```
string taskListUrlById = "{0}_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('tasks')/items(932)"; //932 is the ID of the item to update
string SiteUrl = "yoursite";
string url = string.Format(taskListUrlById, SiteUrl);
string content = "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.TasksListItem' }, 'Status': 'Close'}";

var credential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username",
                                                  "Password",
                                                   "domain");
                
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = credential, UseProxy = false })
    {
      using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
          var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
          request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
          request.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", await GetRequestDigest());
          request.Headers.Add("X-HTTP-Method", "MERGE");
          request.Headers.Add("IF-MATCH", "*");
          HttpContent strContent = new StringContent(content);
          strContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
          strContent.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("odata", "verbose"));
          request.Content = strContent;
          var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        }
    }
```